# How to remove a specific class from all elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove a given class from the page elements?

Example:

```
<div class="fan light"> ... </div>
<div class="light"> ... </div>
<h3 class="seahorse light"> SomeHeading </h3>
```

I want to drop the class `light` from all elements of the page!

How do I do that using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just find all the elements that *do* have the class, and remove it:

```
$(".light").removeClass("light");
```

With plain JavaScript:

```
var lights = document.getElementsByClassName("light");
while (lights.length)
    lights[0].className = lights[0].className.replace(/\blight\b/g, "");
```

(That relies on the browser supporting `.getElementsByClassName()`.) Note that the loop looks a little weird, always operating on element 0 of the element list. That's because the lists returned from APIs like `.getElementsByClassName()` are **live** — they change to reflect changes in the DOM. When a class is removed from an element, it's no longer in the list of elements with that class name. Thus by removing the class from the first element in the list, that element goes away. Eventually the list will be empty. (I've always thought that this was a bizarre behavior that flagrantly violates the principle of least surprise, but there you go.)

Finally it's pointed out in a comment that newer browsers (IE10+) support a DOM element property called `.classList`. It's a list of class names, plus it supports some handy methods. In particular:

```
var lights = document.getElementsByClassName("light");
while (lights.length)
    lights[0].classList.remove("light");
```

Comment: and where is the `elem.classList.remove()` example? ;)

Comment: @epascarello it takes me a couple years to get used to new-fangled DOM APIs. A large part of my head is devoted to instinctive IE6 decision-making.

Comment: I am in the same boat, but since my job just dropped IE9 support, I am in a world of wonder. Look at all the wonderful things I could never use before!!

Answer (score 4):

Use `jQuery` to find all `DOM` elements with the `class` `light` and remove the `class`.

```
$('.light').removeClass('light');
```

Answer (score 4):

Short plain JavaScript:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('light'), function (el) {
    el.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```