# How remove all elements from a page which contain specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, element

I would like to print off my LinkedIn profile (https://www.linkedin.com/in/peterhorniak/) as my resume. I've removed some unwanted elements using individual lines of JQuery through the Chrome console, such as with these examples:

- $('.header').remove();
- $('.topcard__connections').remove();
- $('.li-footer').remove();

The web page has a Projects section with many blank portraits. I would like to remove all of the portrait elements. I can do so individually, such as these examples:

- document.querySelector("body > main > div.core-rail > section >
  section.projects.pp-section > ul > li:nth-child(27) > ul").remove();
- document.querySelector("body > main > div.core-rail > section >
  section.projects.pp-section > ul > li:nth-child(28) > ul").remove();

There are over 20 such elements. How can I programmatically remove all elements that fulfil the following conditions?

```
 1. they are part of the section <section class="projects pp-section" data-section="projects">
 2. they are part of an unordered list <ul class="projects__list">
 3. they are one of the list elements <li class="projects__project">
 4. within that list element, they are in the unordered list <ul class="face-pile__list projects-face-pile__list">
```

I am running Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I've tried making a loop based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362423/how-to-remove-a-specific-class-from-all-elements). Because the class has a space in it, and based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133722/javascript-invalidcharactererror-when-modifying-a-css-name-with-a-space), I treated it as two classes.

```
var projects = document.getElementsByClassName("face-pile__list", "projects-face-pile__list");
while (projects.length)
    projects[0].classList.remove("face-pile__list", "projects-face-pile__list");
```

I expected this to remove the portraits from each element. Instead it gave the output "undefined".

Comment: Rather than going through and removing things why not just select what you actually want to print?

Comment: Please clarify the question. The title is answered in the first little bit of your body, and the body is very vague. From what I am able to gather, you just want to remove elements by using a selector that contains more than one class. For this, you can simply do `$("face-pile__list.projects-face-pile__list").remove();`

Comment: Hi @EternalHour, thanks for your comment. I have two reasons. Firstly there is a lot more elements that I want to print than elements I want to remove, so it seems quicker to remove them.Secondly, there are many elements that I only want to include for a particular application. I want a script that removes everything that doesn't belong in any application, and then I can manually remove the few elements that aren't suitable for that particular application.

Comment: Hi @JesseGibson, thanks for your suggestion. I've edited the body. I tried running your code and received this error: VM984:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:46

Comment: I forgot a period. Try `$(".face-pile__list.projects-face-pile__list").remove();`

Comment: Hi @JesseGibson, thanks for the update. I tried this and got the result: "undefined".

Comment: Good. That means it did something, or at least didn't have any errors. Did you check to see if the elements were removed?

Comment: It removes the top-most element every time I run it in a script. I kludged together this loop that removes them all, although it gives an error at the end:
var a = 1
while (a=1)
    $(".projects__project-contributors").remove();
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the projects section is loaded before calling those functions.
Since Linkedin uses lazy loading unless you open projects section
manually none of that info will be loaded on the page

```
function removeCreators() {
    const projectSection = document.querySelector('.pv-profile-section.pv-accomplishments-block.projects');
    const contributorsSections = projectSection.querySelectorAll('a[data-control-name="project_contributors"]');
    contributorsSections.forEach( x => x.remove() );
};

function removeEmptyCreatorsImages() {
  const projectSection = document.querySelector('.pv-profile-section.pv-accomplishments-block.projects');
  const emptyContributors = projectSection.querySelectorAll('img.ghost-person');
  emptyContributors.forEach( x => x.remove() );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Illia Chaban, thanks for the answer. I believe the projects section loaded, because I can see the portraits on the web page, and I also see them in the Elements tab when I open the Chrome console. 

When I run those functions I get the result "undefined", and when I then run "removeCreators() I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at removeCreators (<anonymous>:3:49)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
Am I doing it right please?